USPS Shipping Options API v3 - "The request body is invalid or malformed" Error (400)
I'm trying to use the USPS Shipping Options API v3 with Python's requests library to retrieve shipping rates. I successfully obtain an OAuth token, but when I call get_usps_rate to get quotes, I receive a 400 error with the message:

"The request body is invalid or malformed."

def get_usps_rate(access_token, origin_zip, destination_zip, weight, length, height, width, mail_class):
url = f"{BASE_URL}/shipments/v3/options/search"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

payload = {
    "pricingOptions": [
        {
            "priceType": "RETAIL"
        }
    ],
    "originZIPCode": origin_zip,
    "destinationZIPCode": destination_zip,
    "packageDescription": {
        "weight": weight,
        "length": length,
        "height": height,
        "width": width,
        "mailClass": mail_class
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
if response.status_code == 200:
    return response.json()
else:
    print(f"Request payload: {payload}")
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
    raise Exception(f"Error fetching USPS rate: {response.json()}")

I have reviewed the USPS Shipping Options API documentation for common errors and data format requirements.(https://developer.usps.com/shippingoptionsv3)
I've tried simplifying the request by removing optional fields, but still receive the same error.

According to the documentation, the pricingOptions section is also supposed to contain a paymentAccount item.  Is there a reason you did not include that in your request?

And there are also other missing items in the packageDescription section, such as girth, packageValue, and mailingDate.

According to the documentation (https://developer.usps.com/shippingoptionsv3), paymentAccount, girth, packageValue, and mailingDate are not required fields.
